# User with root permissions

Tags: shell

I want to start a program with root privileges when a user (not root) login.
The program or script to be run whenever a user logs in, what do I do about the bashrc file

Thanks.

Comment: Do not use the user's environment for this. It isn't likely to be safe or reliable. Use the login service or pam or some other similar system for this.

Answer (score 0):

set file permissions to start program always from owner and set root as owner:

```
sudo chown root:root /bin/your_program
sudo chmod 2755 /bin/your_program
```

add your program to user autostart file

```
echo "/bin/your_program&" >> ~/.profile
```

now program will start with root piviledges when you login into system.

Comment: I test it on my Server.